# How to select a entry in Database using multiple conditions?

Tags: entity-framework, c#-4.0

I'm working on a project for fun, and I am saving the users current GuildId, UserId, their level, and current Exp. It works partially, but it seems to just grab the first result of only one condition.

I've tried a number of different ways of selecting an item from the database but as this is a hobby I feel I'm missing something very obvious. Ive logged my ways of fetching UserId and GuildId and they return the correct values.

It currently adds a new entry if one doesn't exist, and will update the Xp correctly but only for one entry. It seems to ignore the GuildId and just find the first entry matching UserId and save it there.

```
    public static async Task SaveExp(ulong guildId, ulong userId, int level, uint xp, DateTime cooldown)
    {
        using (var dbContext = new DatabaseHandler())
        {
            if (dbContext.Exps.Any(x => x.GuildId == guildId && x.UserId == userId))
            {
                var current = dbContext.Exps.FirstOrDefault(x => x.GuildId == guildId && x.UserId == userId);
                if (current != null)
                {
                    current.Xp += xp;
                    current.Level += level;
                    dbContext.Exps.Update(current);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dbContext.Exps.Add(new Exp
                {
                    GuildId = guildId,
                    UserId = userId,
                    Level = level,
                    Xp = xp,
                    Cooldown = cooldown
                });
            }
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
```

I want it to save the Xp to the entry where both GuildId and UserId criteria are met.

Comment: "It seems to ignore the GuildId and just find the first entry matching UserId " - That is what `FirstOrDefault()` does. Gather multiple matches into a `List<Exps>`.

Comment: This was the answer, thank you. I was able to put it into a list and pull the correct result from there!

Answer (score 0):

You could refactor your code slightly like this to make it more efficient. Your code does do what you are describing though. If you should only ever have a single/null result returned then you should use `SingleOrDefault`/`SingleOrDefaultAsync` which ensures that, more results would result in an `InvalidOperationException`.

```
public static async Task SaveExp(ulong guildId, ulong userId, int level, uint xp, DateTime cooldown)
{
    using (var dbContext = new DatabaseHandler())
    {
        var current = await dbContext.Exps.FirstOrDefaultAsync(x => x.GuildId == guildId && x.UserId == userId);
        if (current != null)
        {
            current.Xp += xp;
            current.Level += level;
            // you should not need this next line in EF6
            // the entity is already attached as you just retrieved it and should be tracked
            dbContext.Exps.Update(current);
        }
        else
        {
            dbContext.Exps.Add(new Exp
            {
                GuildId = guildId,
                UserId = userId,
                Level = level,
                Xp = xp,
                Cooldown = cooldown
            });
        }
        await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
}
```

Comment: I would add, that if OP is trying to add Xps to all the items that match you might grab them into a list and either loop or use `matches.Foreach(x => x.Xp = xp);` or similar.

Comment: @Dnovax - you would need to produce an [mcve] if you wanted additional help. Create a stand alone method (or set of methods) that can reproduce the problem.